# Run Ansible Taks for several Groups in Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, ansible

We have many similar hosts that are grouped to specific types.
Every group has several hosts in it, mostly 2 to 8 for scalability within the type.
Now we need to run the same tasks/role on all these hosts.
Serialised within each group but all groups at the same time.
This should run much faster than all groups (about 10 groups currently) in a row.

Is this possible today with Ansible?

Comment: why not simply run two ansible commands parallelly

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.  I'm afriad I do not have the ability to test this idea, but here goes....

Let's say you have `GroupA` and `GroupB`.  To ping each host in a group serially, but have the groups run in parallel, you could try this hideous construct:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - ping:
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ groups['groupA'] }}"
    forks: 1
    async: 0
    poll: 0
  - ping:
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ groups['groupB'] }}"
    forks: 1
    async: 0
    poll: 0
```

Ansible is still going to show the task output separately.

When I ran this, files were created in `/home/ansible/.ansible_async`.  Those files show the task start times, and it looked like it worked.  To verify, I ran `shell: sleep 5` instead of `ping:`, and saw the start times in those files properly interleaved.

Good luck.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me.
Using this shell:

`shell: "sleep 2 && date +T%T"`

I get this output (edited):

`TASK [groupA] *********

T17:14:37

T17:14:40

TASK [groupB] **********

T17:14:44

T17:14:47
`